# HttpParams на Android Studio не работает

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я недавно начал изучать Android Studio. И вот столкнулся с такой проблемой, `HttpParams` не работает, а точнее оно вычеркнуто в коде. Я и в `build.gradle` добавлял много чего, но ничего не помогает.
Вот кусок кода и `build.gradle`:

```
private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams()
{
    HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, 1000 * 30);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, 1000 * 30);
    return httpRequestParams;
}
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lado.synchronization"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вообщето если вычеркнуто это означает устарело и желательно использовать чтото другое.Но оно работает.а так используй Retrofit